# Subset of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ with finite vertical cross sections and cofinite horizontal cross sections

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Does there exist a set $S \subseteq [0,1] \times [0,1]$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) such that:

- for all $x$, $\{y : (x,y) \in S\}$ is finite; and
- for all $y$, $\{x : (x,y) \notin S\}$ is finite?

In other words, the vertical cross section at any $x$-coordinate is finite, while the horizontal cross section at any $y$-coordinate is cofinite.

---

This question is purely set-theoretic, as $[0,1]$ could be replaced by any set of cardinality $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$. I am just using $[0,1]$ to aid with intuition.

The total cardinality is the same counting in the horizontal or vertical direction first, so I can't think of an easy reason why such an $S$ would not exist.

$S$ necessarily has outer (Lebesgue) measure $1$ and inner (Lebesgue) measure $0$.
In particular $S$ is not measurable.

Since $S$ is not measurable I believe the answer to this will depend on some form of the axiom of choice. What I would most like to see is a construction of $S$ assuming choice, or a proof that $S$ cannot exist.

Comment: I don't think that the AC tag fits here; it's more of a tag for question *about* the axiom, not question whose answer is expected to use the axiom.

Comment: My guess is that if this can be done, then you should probably begin by well-ordering $[0,1]$, and the finite subsets of $[0,1]$, then by induction somehow construct $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is enough to work in $\omega_1 \times \omega_1$. Suppose $S_n = \{y : (n, y) \in S\}$ is countable for each $n < \omega$. Choose a $y < \omega_1$ outside the union of $S_n$'s. Then $((\omega_1 \times \omega_1) \setminus S)^y = \{x : (x, y) \notin S\}$ is infinite.

Comment: Ah of course. OK, thank you.